# Yelp package building problem

Tags: packaging, yelp

I'm using Ubuntu12.04 lts.

When I built the `yelp` package from it's source with `dpkg-buildpackage` command, It shows me following message,

and It fall a sleep.

```
gtk-doc: Scanning header files

(process:30532): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
```

What happened?
How do i solve this problem?

Comment: I also have this problem, I think that it problem is related with the environment variables when build debian package with dpkg-buildpackage command.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem as following

I downloaded `yelp` source from ubuntu repository with `apt-get source yelp`.

I opened `yelp-3.4.1/debian/rules`, removed following line.

```
DEB_CONFIGURE_EXTRA_FLAGS += --enable-gtk-doc
```

BTW, I could build the `yelp` package.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to implement difficult compilation methods to install yelp. It is in [main Ubuntu repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=yelp&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all).

[image: Install via the software center]

```
sudo apt-get install yelp libyelp0 libyelp-dev unity-scope-yelp yelp-tools yelp-xsl
```